# Benefits of using Maps vs Symbols to associate data in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an array `arr`. I want to be able to associate certain metadata with `arr` that I can access in other functions. I can see two straightforward ways to do this: First, I could create a `Map` that uses `arr` as the key and the metadata as the value.

```js
const arrDataMap = new Map();
function getArrMetadata(arr) {
    if(!arrDataMap.has(arr)) {
        arrDataMap.set(arr, generateArrData(arr));
    }
    return arrDataMap.get(arr);
}
```

Or second, I could store the metadata directly in the array using a `Symbol`.

```js
const arrDataSymbol = Symbol("ArrMetadata");
function getArrMetadata(arr) {
    if(!Object.hasOwn(arr, arrDataSymbol)) {
        arr[arrDataSymbol] = generateArrData(arr);
    }
    return arr[arrDataSymbol];
}
```

Both of these solutions would work, but I'm having trouble getting a sense of the drawbacks of each one. The first option has the overhead of the `Map` object to contend with, but the second option involves treating `arr` like a standard, non-array object by storing a key/value in it — which I assume is a bad practice.

What do y'all think?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with storing properties on the array object, so long as you understand how they work. For something specifically like what you're talking about, the fact that the metadata won't be serialized by `JSON.stringify()` and won't count towards the `.length` value is probably not a problem, and in fact is probably what you want anyway.

Comment: Also you should probably add the property as non-enumerable using `Object.defineProperty()`.

Comment: @Pointy ah my understanding was that Symbol keys are non-enumerable by default. Is that not the case?

Comment: yea that may be the case, I am in the habit of using `Object.defineProperty()` for things like that as a general "hygiene" rule.

Comment: You could also use `WeakMap` advantage been that when everything goes out of scope, your not holding onto memory you no longer need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first option has the overhead of the Map object to contend with

It's not that much of an overhead. An advantage over the symbol approach is that it is not observable/accessible on the array object. It also works when frozen arrays are passed on which it is not possible to create a new property.

Another ~advantage~ difference is that you have an iterable collection of all arrays for which you stored data, should you ever need this.

> The second option involves treating arr like a standard, non-array object by storing a key/value in it — which I assume is a bad practice.

Nah, this is totally fine. And you even went to use symbols so that the properties do not collide with anything else.

An advantage over the `Map` approach is that the data is stored only on each array, and will get garbage-collected when the array is no longer needed, whereas the `Map` even holds onto the arrays and will lead to memory leaks. This would require a `WeakMap` to solve.